# dynamic <a href> event without replacing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Hey im having a problem creating a dynamic ahref event. The problem is that i dont want it to perform the default event of just linking. So i have blocked the default and want to replace content inside a div like so, here is the working code:

```
echo '<a href="/mydirectory/index.php?id=',$id,'">';
echo '<script>
$( "a" ).click(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
 $(".container2").load("/mydirectory/index.php?id=',$id,'");';
echo '}); </script>';
```

This works perfectly as i expeted, the problem is that by using this:

```
$( "a" ).click(function( event ) {
```

It sets all elements of 'a' on the page to link to the last link clicked. However using a unique ID on the href seems to redirect just directly to the html rather than replacing the content and there are no errors when i checked on chrome:

```
<a href="/mydirectory/index.php?id=',$id,'" id="mylink">
$( "#mylink" ).click(function( event ) {
```

So my question is simply, how do i retain the functionality that seems to work for some reason only on the a href and stop it replacing all the a-hrefs elsewhere in the site with the same function?

Comment: Define a unique class or id to the anchor tag?

Comment: The answer is simple too, try to change the `color` of that specific `anchor tag` using `css`, if you get success, do the same way to target the anchor tag in js as well

Comment: How many link you have and how are generated html or dynamic ?

Comment: I have around 4-5 other uses of a-href on the site which link elsewhere on the site however when i use the method above the links are replaced, and im trying to find a way to add the ones above without replacing all other <a-hrefs>

Comment: add an answer check if is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how many link and how you generated anyway you can use 'click' function and get the attr href than use it how you like. Than over preventDefault use event.stopImmediatePropagation() look the code if you have any question let me know

```
<a href="/mydirectory/index.php?id=',$id,'" id="mylink">click me</a>

$('a#mylink').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var link_url = $(this).attr('href');

    alert(link_url);

    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention if you use an unique id you have to call with '#' and not with '.' used for a class so your code should in this way

```
<a href="/mydirectory/index.php?id=',$id,'" id="mylink">
$( "#mylink" ).click(function( event ) {
```

Comment: ah thanks this is true, but the problem remains for some reason even when this is fixed but i'll update the code.